# Divi Builder not display Default editor

Tags: php, wordpress

When I'm using Divi Builder in my Website, The default editor not display. It display one button 'Use Default Editor'. When I click on that button, It show dialog box with 'All content created in the Divi Builder will be lost. Previous content will be restored. Do you wish to proceed?' content.

So, How can I use default editor without lost my data?

Comment: https://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/documentation/builder-overview/ please refer this link

Comment: I check this documentation. But I can't find proper solution.

Comment: Please, Provide solution for complete my requirement without data lost.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem with me, it turns out that some ACTIVE plugins might be crashing with libraries of your DIVI theme. My solution was to deactivate my plugins and then return to my DIVI Builder and everything was there again.

Hope this solution helps, It's what I've tried and got me back on track.

Answer (score 0):

This is really annoying, but there is a way. If you look into Inspect Element (on Chrome), then search for "wp-editor-area", you'll see they have hidden the shortcodes rendering from the user. Really ANNOYING.

The trick is then to trigger jQuery to copy and paste the content of that  into the wordpress default, when you click on USE DEFAULT EDITOR button.

Answer (score 0):

This is the biggest rub when using DIVI. Even with the recent update, this is still the default behavior of a DIVI build. So, reverting to the Default Editor will remove all of your content. Here is an article that outlines this in greater detail:

http://chrislema.com/divi-theme-forever/

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Divi > Theme Options > Builder > Advanced > Enable the builder(Classic builder)**